# For Each Loop dependant options

Tags: excel, vba, loops, offset

While working on a loop which works, I want to create a dependant choice.

The user must select on Sheet2 whether a product will be shown on sheet1 or not by hiding the row. If he wants a product to be shown, he must fill in "a" in the Range("Checkmark"). See image below.

[image: Image1]

VBA will then search with a code which products have an "a" and take the named range of that cell and add an "1" after it so the named range on sheet1 will be hidden or unhidden. For example, if product A is selected, VBA will take Named range "ProductA" and make it into "ProductA1". Named range "ProductA1" will then be shown on sheet 1. See images below.

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

The second choice is whether the product must be black or white. If chosen "black" then a certain named range on sheet 1 will be shown and "white" will be hidden. It could also be the other way around. The product itself contains some info named "Productinfo". This should be shown if an "a" has been filled in on sheet 2 under checkmark, if the product is not selected, all rows (Named range "ProductA1") should be hidden for that product on sheet 1. See images below.

[image: Image4]

[image: Image5]

See all named ranges in image below.

[image: Image6]

So this is the code:

```
    Sub Choosingproduct()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("Checkmark") 'Where user puts in value "a" or not
'Searching for the products that have an "a" in checkmark, then replacing the name and adding a "1" so VBA knows which range to hide or unhide on sheet 1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Replace(cell.Name.Name, cell.Name.Name, cell.Name.Name & "1")).EntireRow.Hidden = Not cell.Value = "a"


    Dim rCell As Range
    For Each rCell In Range("Productchoice")
    If cell.Value = "a" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Replace(rCell.Name.Name, rCell.Name.Name, rCell.Name.Name & "black")).EntireRow.Hidden = Not rCell.Value = "Black"
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Replace(rCell.Name.Name, rCell.Name.Name, rCell.Name.Name & "white")).EntireRow.Hidden = Not rCell.Value = "White"
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Replace(rCell.Name.Name, rCell.Name.Name, rCell.Name.Name & "black")).EntireRow.Hidden = Not rCell.Value = "Black"
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Replace(rCell.Name.Name, rCell.Name.Name, rCell.Name.Name & "white")).EntireRow.Hidden = Not rCell.Value = "White"
    End If

    Next rCell

Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

How can I make VBA search for each separate component in the second loop? I get the run-time error 1004, Application-defined or object-defined error.

UPDATE:

I tried a different code and this seems to work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cell As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In Range("Checkmark") 'Where user puts in value "a" or not
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Replace(cell.Name.Name, cell.Name.Name, cell.Name.Name & "1")).EntireRow.Hidden = Not cell.Value = "a"

        If cell.Value = "a" Then
            If Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Replace(cell.Name.Name, cell.Name.Name, cell.Name.Name & "choice")).Value = "Black" Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Replace(cell.Name.Name, cell.Name.Name, cell.Name.Name & "choiceblack")).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Else
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Replace(cell.Name.Name, cell.Name.Name, cell.Name.Name & "choiceblack")).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If

        If cell.Value = "a" Then
            If Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Replace(cell.Name.Name, cell.Name.Name, cell.Name.Name & "choice")).Value = "White" Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Replace(cell.Name.Name, cell.Name.Name, cell.Name.Name & "choicewhite")).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Else
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Replace(cell.Name.Name, cell.Name.Name, cell.Name.Name & "choicewhite")).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If

Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Trim down your code and post am easily reproducable example.

Comment: @DavidG I've made the update, hope this is better. However, I get a different error code at the beginning which I didn''t have in the old code.

Comment: @DavidG, Disregard the different error code at the beginning. It is just the second loop that is troubling me now.

Comment: By "troublin me now" you mean the error 1004? Or did you encounter a new error now? At what line do you get the error?

Comment: @DavidG, the error 1004 code for the first loop is what I meant, but that one was because I was referring to the wrong sheet. I got the code working with a different code for this example. Maybe I can show you it through a chat? Or should I update it above?

Comment: It is best to always update your question with new results, so others can see them as well. And be as specific as possible with your descriptions.